# Why does CORS block my fetch in Bolero (F# Blazor) although configuration follows documentation?

Tags: asp.net-core, f#, cors, blazor, bolero

I am writing a Bolero (F# Blazor) application, and I am running into some issues regarding CORS when trying to challenge GitHub for authentication. I've handled similar CORS error messages in other languages previously, so CORS isn't *that* new to me. The message looks like this:

[image: CORS error message]

Going to the URL manually works just fine.

I've read and applied the documentation from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0), as well as other SO posts with the same or similar problems, eg. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62863417/blazor-cannot-connect-to-asp-net-core-webapi-cors) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64858434/net5-0-blazor-wasm-cors-client-exception). I've created a repro which might be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/maritiren/repro-bolero-github-oauth). These are the steps I've taken to reproduce the issue:

1. Create the Bolero template `bolero-app` with both client and server.
2. Change authentication to GitHub OAuth2.0 ([AspNet.Security.OAuth.GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers))
3. Add CORS in `Startup.fs`. Both in `Configure` and `ConfigureServices`.

Reproducing issue when running the application:

1. Run the application. I use `dotnet run -p src/ReproGithubOAuth.Server`.
2. Navigate to the `Download data` page, open the console tab in the inspect view.
3. Now you can click the `Sign in` button and should see the same error as the picture above.

This is how I challenge GitHub, through the remote service (see code [here](https://github.com/maritiren/repro-bolero-github-oauth/blob/main/src/ReproGithubOAuth.Server/BookService.fs#L37) in GitHub):

```ml
signIn = fun () -> async {
    let! res = Async.AwaitTask (ctx.HttpContext.ChallengeAsync "GitHub")
    printfn $"res: {res}"
    // Do some parsing of request
    // Never gets this far, so returning whatever
    return option.Some "myusername"
}
```

As for the configuration in `Startup.fs` (see code [here](https://github.com/maritiren/repro-bolero-github-oauth/blob/main/src/ReproGithubOAuth.Server/Startup.fs#L22) in GitHub):

```ml
member this.ConfigureServices(services: IServiceCollection) =
        let configureCors (builder: Infrastructure.CorsPolicyBuilder) = 
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5000")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
                |> ignore
...
        services.AddCors(fun options ->
            options.AddPolicy("_allowSpecificOrigins", configureCors)
        ) |> ignore
        services
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddAuthentication(fun options ->
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme <- CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
                options.DefaultSignInScheme <- CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme <- "GitHub"
            )
                .AddCookie(fun config ->
                    config.Cookie.SameSite <- SameSiteMode.None
                    config.Cookie.SecurePolicy <- CookieSecurePolicy.Always
                )
                .AddGitHub(fun options ->
                    options.ClientId <- "GitHub ClientId should be here";
                    options.ClientSecret <- "GitHub Client Secret should be here"; 
                    options.CallbackPath <- new PathString("/github-oauth");
                    options.AuthorizationEndpoint <- "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize";
                    options.TokenEndpoint <- "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token";
                    options.UserInformationEndpoint <- "https://api.github.com/user";
                )
                .Services
         |> ignore
...

member this.Configure(app: IApplicationBuilder, env: IWebHostEnvironment) =
        // Putting UseCors() after UseRouting() according to 
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/65937838/12094643
        app
            .UseRouting()
            .UseCors("_allowSpecificOrigins")
...
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff. I've basically tried all the fixes in the posts I've read so far except [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128807/12094643) saying that I should use `await Http.GetJsonAsync<put here your return type>("/api/Login/Test");`, which just doesn't make sense to me when challenging GitHub from the remote service.

Appreciate all help that I can get <3

Comment: I cloned your repository, but was unable to reproduce the error. I created a new GitHub app and put the client ID and secret in Startup.fs with callback URL: "https://localhost:44383/github-oauth". When I run the app and click on the "Sign in" button, I get what looks like a client-side error: "One or more errors occurred. (TypeError: Failed to fetch)". Is there anything else I need to change in order to reproduce what you're seeing?

Comment: `WithOrigins("https://github.com")` ?

Comment: @brianberns Yes exactly, I will clear this out in my post. If you open the console, you will see that the fetch fails due to CORS.

Comment: @jhr As far as I've understood CORS, the origin is the site fetching the resource. So in my case localhost:5000. You can read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS. The second example from that site shows a preflighted request in which the site `http://foo.example` fetches data from `https://bar.other`, then `http://foo.example` is the origin and the responding request from `https://bar.other` has to respond with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example` header.

Comment: I did try that origin though, @jhr . It didn't work.

Comment: Right, but your CORS policy can't change Github's CORS policy. There's an `AllowAnyOrigin` instead of `WithOrigin` you can use to allow all and test if its your site's CORS. Also noticed in your Startup.Configure you dont have `app.UseAuthorization();` [oauth doc](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers#getting-started) And the sample doesn't even `AddCors`: [sample startup](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/blob/dev/samples/Mvc.Client/Startup.cs)  /2cents