# GRPC-Web + Blazor CORS Issue

Tags: c#, cors, blazor, grpc, grpc-web

I'm trying to create a Blazor WASM application that will call a GRPC gateway using grpc-web.

The description of the Gateway Service is:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "Services/AdService.proto";

package BonnieAndClydesdale.Core;

service GatewayService {
  rpc GetAds (AdRequest) returns (AdReply);
}
```

I've followed [this guide](https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2020/01/15/2020-01-15-grpc-web-in-blazor-webassembly/#adding-grpc-services-to-a-blazor-webassembly-application) to set-up grpc-web on server and client.

I have this in the `program.cs` of my server:

```cs
builder.Services.AddGrpc();
builder.Services.AddGrpcReflection();
builder.Services.AddGrpcClient<AdService.AdServiceClient>(o => o.Address = new("https://localhost:7223")); // Downstream GRPC service

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.MapGrpcService<GatewayService>().EnableGrpcWeb();
app.UseGrpcWeb();
```

And this in the `program.cs` of my blazor app:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton(services => 
                              {
                                  HttpClient httpClient = new(new GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb, new HttpClientHandler()));
                                  string baseUri = "https://localhost:7080"; // TODO - Add to AppSettings 
                                  GrpcChannel channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(baseUri, new() { HttpClient = httpClient });
                                  return new GatewayService.GatewayServiceClient(channel); 
                              });
```

However, when I load this page:

```cs
public partial class ForSale: ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    private GatewayService.GatewayServiceClient Client { get; init; } = null!;//TODO replace with service
    private readonly List<AdDetails> _ads;

    public ForSale()
    {
        _ads = new();
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        AdReply? rep = await Client.GetAdsAsync(new());
        if (rep.AdDetails is not null)
        {
            _ads.AddRange(rep.AdDetails);
        }
    }
    
}
```

I'm getting a CORS error:

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://localhost:7080/BonnieAndClydesdale.Core.GatewayService/GetAds'
> from origin 'https://localhost:5001' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Any ideas on how to approach fixing this?

---

*EDIT*

I've seen a lot of answers to similar questions that suggest using `services.AddCors(...)` and `app.UseCors()` but these methods don't seem to exist on Blazor WASM apps.

Comment: Have you looked at the following questions and answers? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64858434/441757, https://stackoverflow.com/q/65858468/441757, https://stackoverflow.com/q/68250161/441757, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62863417/441757

Comment: @sideshowbarker - Yes... but `services.AddCors(...)` doesn't seem to exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue arose from a misunderstanding as to *where* the CORS policy needed to be set. It needed to be set in the gateway server rather than on the Blazor WASM web-app. This makes sense since CORS is implemented on the server but the confusion arose because most tutorials seem to assume that we're using Blazor Server.

For the sake of completeness, I added this to the `startup.cs` of my *gateway* (not the Blazor App).

```cs
const string corsPolicy = "_corsPolicy";
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
                         {
                             options.AddPolicy(name: corsPolicy,
                                               policy  =>
                                               {
                                                   policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5001",
                                                                      "http://localhost:5000")
                                                         .AllowAnyHeader()
                                                         .AllowAnyMethod();
                                               });
                         });
WebApplication app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors(corsPolicy);
```